# Group Policy / Roaming Profile Issue

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, roaming-profile

I am running a Server 03 DC and this is happening on a Windows 7 PC. Each time we tried logging in as the user the only thing coming up is a temp profile. We thought it might be an issue with the way the OU/ GP was set up so we created a new OU and moved that user into it. Roaming Profiles is not set in this OU. Still each time we try logging in we're still getting the same temp profile issue.
I am leaning towards there is an issue with AD but I want to make sure. Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're `"leaning towards there is an issue with AD"` it sounds like you'd be leaning in the wrong direction. You haven't provided a whole lot of details, but from the little that you've posted, I'd put my money on "You probably still have roaming profiles accidentally applying to that profile even in the new OU. Check that the permissions for that profile on the share are correct."

Comment: Check with gpresult/rsop.msc what is actually being applied here, this doesn't sound right.

Comment: If you look at the profiles on System Properties are they showing as Roaming?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit spotty-- you don't enable roaming profiles on an OU, for example. Some more details would be helpful.

I would strongly suspect that you haven't created a ".V2" profile folder for the user and the user doesn't have permissions to create one on the server themselves.

Have a look at the Event Log on the client computer. It's trying to tell you what's wrong.